# unique identifier (long) in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `class` that is named as `Letter`. And it has `myId` (long) property. 
when i use this Class, i want `myId` to be like this:

```
Letter *obj1 = [[Letter alloc] init]
Letter *obj1 = [[Letter alloc] init]
Letter *obj1 = [[Letter alloc] init]
```

`obj1.myId` must be 1
`obj2.myId` must be 2
`obj3.myId` must be 3

I have tried this:

```
@interface Letter : NSObject

@property (atomic) long myId;

- (instancetype)initWithId;

@end

@implementation Letter

- (instancetype) initWithId
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil){
        _myId ++ ;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

But it's not working. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `static` global variable to keep track of the id:

```
@implementation Letter

static long _id = 1;

- (instancetype) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil){
        _myId = _id++;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

(note I have removed the `initWithId` method in favour of plain-old `init`).

Comment: if i have `SequenceGenerator` class and it has class method named as `next`. `_myId = [SequenceGenerator next]`. can i do like this?

Comment: @AyubxonUbaydullayev I guess, if `SequenceGenerator` keeps track of the id in a similar way, however this should have been part of your question.